How would families function in a polyamorous society?
In my society, it is normal for groups of two, three, and four to live together and raise a family. Within a group, not all members are necessarily married to each other. As per the chart below, there are many different possible combinations.
I am trying to figure out how families would function under such a system.
• Which one of their families would a newly married group move in with?
• Would all guardians have a responsibility to help raise all of the children, or only the ones they share DNA with?
• Would houses be larger, to accommodate these larger families?


This is not possible to answer as nearly every single one will function differently. Adults will care for all children but will always have certain ones they favor.

VTC:Too Story-Based. How any relationship will work depends far too much on too many things that are dependent on your story. The characteristics of the species (if not human), the underlying culture, religion, philosophy, politics... even the economy would have an impact. The fact that you're allowing married (politically or religiously contracted unions with obligations) to combine with unmarried connections suggests a shift in morality that's very different from most if not all structures on Earth. To add to the problem, what does "function" mean? That's very broad. (*Continued*)

... And finally, you're asking multiple questions and Stack Exchange has a one-question-per-post rule. Yes, they're all related, but that's often how questions become too broad and therefore off-topic. Frankly, this is one of those issues that's better suited for the Stack if you make your choices about how all this works and then ask for our help rationalizing it (if that help is needed after the choice is made).

Without wishing to be too unhelpful, the answer is that they'll function how you need them to function for your story. But there are real world examples you can look to for inspiration, starting with "simple" extended families where relatives live together and share childcare though probably don't have sexual relationships.

JBH voted to close this for being too story-based. That is, you can find many different answers, all with their own advantages, disadvantages, and consequences, and it is up to you as a writer to pick the right one for your story.
That being said,

A nuclear family is often understood to be a union of adults, plus their children if any. From your examples, you seem to be tinkering with the concept of the nuclear family, not bonds of extended relations. The traditional purpose of the nuclear family is to raise children and to care for each other, both valuable societal functions. So you might be able to describe workable societies where these functions are given a bigger bus factor.
In many societies, sexual activity is traditionally allowed only between the adult members of the family, who must not be biologically related. This is often coupled with an expectation of heterosexual couples actually having kids as the default.

In modern Western societies, both of these are weakening. But there is some backslash against it, and historically there was a good reason for these traditions -- childbirth was risky, infant mortality was high, pension systems were few.
You should find ways in which your group marriages work as well or better than heterosexual pairs, and structure your society around that.

Are all adult partners socially expected to be roughly the same age, or is it possible for younger partners to enter? That could leave your question of where a new group lives moot. There are very few truly new groups, and they are only formed if they have secured a place to live.
It might be that some biological parents have slightly more responsibility to their own offspring, but a prime reason for having group marriages is to assure that children are taken care of.
Do you know the Christian tradition of godparents? Once upon a time, they were expected to step in if something happened to the biological parents.
From those two, of course houses would be scaled for typical group sizes. A group marriage living in two houses would be slightly awkward, like a modern couple discussing split bedrooms.


"Family is often understood to be a union of adults, plus their children if any": I don't know, maybe this is the case in America. In most parts of the world, that thing would be called a nuclear family, while the word family in general would be understood to apply to many more people. My brother, his wife my sister-in-law, his son my nephew, his wife and son are definitely "family". It is common at family functions to have four generations present.

@AlexP, yes, I was thinking of the nuclear family. But the OP also seems to have used the term that way, see the examples. I'll clarify.
